# Where can I get netpacket/packet.h file for QNX neutrino?

Tags: qnx

I am trying to build a library to use SOEM on QNX.  However, when I go to build, I get the following error:

> Installing the build libraries
>   Scanning dependencies of target soem
>   [ 4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/soem.dir/C_/SOEM-master/oshw/linux/nicdrv.c.o
>   **C:/SOEM-master/oshw/linux/nicdrv.c:80:30: fatal error: netpacket/packet.h: No such file or directory**
>   compilation terminated.

I have found packet.h files but none of them seem to be right for this build. I am not having any luck blindly searching on google for it. It is not in my build of QNX itself, so I am not sure if it even exists. 
What is the best way to search for it? Where could I possibly find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netpacket/packet.h does not exist for QNX.

Apparently there is a lot more than just 1 different header file for building for QNX compared to the Linux build I was trying to use.  One of my coworkers had already spent time to convert from Linux build to QNX build.  So I just used what they created.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see when current header is wrong - try to find network patches for your target. There should be another version of the header.